# `loadingIndicator` nuxt.config.js property not working for Universal mode? Is it expected?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, loading

By default nuxt provides two nuxt.config.js properties **loading** & **loadingIndicator**. **loading** works perfectly fine in my nuxt project but I would like to make use of **loadingIndicator** on page load for the very first time but it doesn't seem to work.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator/

However as per the nuxt documentation it does mention that this option is for SPA mode but I was wondering if not this is there anything else for Universal mode?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change universal mode to spa mode

```
export default { mode: "spa", loadingIndicator: { name: "circle", color:"#f39151", background: "#033641" } };
```